# Show attribute value which applies to all items in a category

Tags: magento2, attributes, filter

Let's say I have a shop which  is specialized in organic food but still offers non-organic food. All items have the attribute "organic" with the options "yes", "partially" and "no".

There is a category "coffee". All coffee in my shop is organic. When a user selects the coffee category, the value "yes" for the "organic" filter will not be shown because all items use this value.

I'd like to show this "yes" value because I want to emphasize for the users that all coffee is organic.

*Is there a solution for this? Can this configured via the UI? If not, where in the source code can I change this behaviour?*

Comment: You can explicitly call attribute value below product name like:
`organic:Yes`. it will show in each product and have more visibility!

Comment: @Pawan Yeah sure, but I still need it to show up in the filters!